# Creating NSDate from NSDateComponents off by one day

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to set a particular date for a unit test:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setCalendar:calendar];
[components setYear:2011];
[components setMonth:5];
[components setDay:12];
[components setHour:1];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"Date I tried to set: %@", date);
```

However, this prints out "Date I tried to set: 2011-05-11 17:00:00 +0000." The date seems off by one day, and I have no idea why it's printing out the time as 17:00:00. 
Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

NSDate doesn't have any timezone data associated with it.  It is actually just a number of seconds from "the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT."  So the date components and calendar are creating an NSDate using your local timezone.  That NSDate is the correct number of seconds from 1/1/2001 00:00 GMT, but when you log it, it's showing you the date in GMT instead of the local timezone.  If you adjust that logged time to your timezone, it will be 2011-05-12 01:00:00.

Comment: How do you adjust the logged time to my time zone? I've tried    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setCalendar:calendar];
[components setYear:2011];
[components setMonth:5];
[components setDay:12];
[components setHour:1];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

or maybe you want

```
 [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```