# Create a NSDate with timezone

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to create a date in ios with:

```
 NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
        [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        NSDateComponents *dateComponentes=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

        //We create a date invented.
        [dateComponentes setYear:2014];
        [dateComponentes setMonth:2];
        [dateComponentes setDay:15];
        [dateComponentes setHour:0];
        [dateComponentes setMinute:0];
        [dateComponentes setSecond:0];
        [dateComponentes setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

        NSDate *initialDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponentes];
```

The thing is, my current time zone is BST, but when I print the time I get this:

```
(lldb) po [initialDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]]
Saturday, 15 February 2014 00:00:00 Greenwich Mean Time
```

But should I get the 2014-02-14 23:00:00 +0000 for this date? :

```
(lldb) po [initialDate description]
2014-02-15 00:00:00 +0000
```

I tried with NSDate and is right,

```
(lldb) po [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]] 
Thursday, 29 May 2014 16:35:21 British Summer Time

(lldb) po [[NSDate date] description]
2014-05-29 15:35:26 +0000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of about a hundred other questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318249/creating-nsdate-from-nsdatecomponents-off-by-one-day?rq=1

Comment: In my example, I'm setting the time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is in February, which is in the winter, when England is on UTC. Your second example is after the DST switch, when England is UTC+1. Play around with the dates using [timeanddate's World Clock](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20140529T00&p1=136&p2=0) and you'll see that `NSCalendar` is correctly computing the `NSDate`.

Comment: Fristly thanks for your answer, Yes you are totally right. But actually my problem was I was creating the initial date with the code above and more dates with: [initialDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24) * i];
So I was creating dates for every day in a range. Unfortunatelly this dates were saved with the same NSTimeZone because is an increment. That made me think! :) Thanks